# Copy files in Java Using JNI

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, file-copying

How can I copy files in Java using JNI on OS X?

Comment: Why do you think that you need to use JNI to copy files???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use JNI to copy files. If you are looking for performance with copying a lot of files you should take a look at the new [Java NIO File Channels.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JNI to copy files. The standard J2SE libraries will handle this. For a more powerful library, see [Apache Commons IO FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).